# Customising tableviewcell in Xamarin ios with MVVMCross

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am using MVVMCross in my Xamarin application. I am able to display some data in a tableview, Now I need to customise the tableview cell to add accessory and allow user to go to next screen on selection of a row. How can I achieve it?
My code to display the tableview:

```
public partial class SchoolSelectionView : MvxViewController<SchoolSelectionViewModel>
    {
        public SchoolSelectionView() : base("SchoolSelectionView", null)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            this.NavigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden(true,true);

            var source = new MvxStandardTableViewSource(tblSchoolSelection, "TitleText Name");
            this.CreateBinding(source).To<SchoolSelectionViewModel>(vm => vm.Items).Apply();
            this.CreateBinding(source).For(s => s.SelectionChangedCommand).To<SchoolSelectionViewModel>(vm => vm.ItemSelectedCommand).Apply();
            tblSchoolSelection.Source = source;
            //tblSchoolSelection.Source = new SchoolListTableSource(this.ViewModel.Items, this);
            tblSchoolSelection.ReloadData();
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ustomise the tableview cell to add accessory

Create a subclass inherit from `MvxTableViewSource` and  override the `GetOrCreateCellFor` method.

```
var source = new MyTableViewSource(tblSchoolSelection, "TitleText Name");

public class MyTableViewSource: MvxStandardTableViewSource {
    override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
    {
        var cell= tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier);
        if (cell== null)
        {
            //xxxx
        }

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Refer to [Custom MvxTableViewCell Without a NIB File](https://benjaminhysell.com/archive/2014/04/mvvmcross-custom-mvxtableviewcell-without-a-nib-file/)

> allow user to go to next screen on selection of a row

Just add `ShowViewModel` in `ItemSelectedCommand` in viewModel.

```
private IMvxCommand _itemSelectedCommand;
public IMvxCommand ItemSelectedCommand
{
    get
    {
        _itemSelectedCommand= _itemSelectedCommand?? new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<NextScreenModel>());
        return _itemSelectedCommand;
    }
}
```